# Imported RSS items have No State and are possibly editable by Anonymous?

Tags: feeds, nodes, workbench

Sometimes RSS feed items come in with No State (as opposed to Draft) and seem to be available for editable by Anonymous?!

Until one goes into edit or Save an RSS Feed item, the Content Moderation state shows as No State instead of Draft!

How does one go about setting the default import Content Moderation State? Is this in Workflow or the Content Type of the feed?